# .htaccess не работает при прямом обращение к файлам типа скриптов и стилей

Tags: .htaccess, кэширование, apache2.4

Всем привет.
В .htaccess прописано:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
```

Ломаю мозг уже 2-й день. Никак не соображу в чем дело.
Вот примеры:
**http://anrits.com/js/cookie.js**

```
Выдает заголовок (где мой Cache-Control?):
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 12:41:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 1293
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 07:03:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "598027d9-50d"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

А например **http://anrits.com/pages/404.php**
Выдает заголовок со всеми параметрами которые есть в .htaccess

```
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 12:45:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public
Expires: Thu, 31 Aug 2017 12:45:54 GMT
```

Еще пример, главная страница выдает два раза Cache-Control
**http://anrits.com/**

```
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 12:50:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 12:50:20 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=gkjofa3ldvoqfpr1bb2v42mj70; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public
```

Как видно Expires тут игнорируется и берется из конфигов default, а Cache-Control должен был быть изменен, а он просто его в конец вставил. Волшебство да и только.

Подскажите хоть в какую сторону копать? Пересмотрел кучу примеров настроек apache и .htaccess, так и не понял почему файлы JS и CSS, а также картинки стороной обходят. А вот .ttf выдает корректные заголовки.
PS: В .htaccess также прописаны настройки сжатия файлов и реврайтинг.

Comment: А то что у вас `Server: nginx/1.10.1` вас не смущает? :)

Comment: Нет, а почему это должно смущать?

Comment: Потому что .htaccess предназначен только для apache, но не для nginx. У вас на сервере, всего вероятнее, наружу смотрит nginx и он же отдает всю статику (js, картинки и т.п.), а за ним спрятан apache, в котором php работает.